methodology for design quantum circuits according to a given unitary
This is a general question. Given an arbitratry unitary matrix.
How to desigin a quantum circuit to implement it?
I am not asking for a specific unitary matrix, but for a general methodology to tackle this issue for an arbitray unitary matrix.
I remembered there is a theorem which says any unitary matrix could be implemented by several gates and it seems that the proof of this theorem is a constructive proof.
However, it doesn't guarantee the circuit complexity.
My question can be specified as given an $2^n\times 2^n$ unitary matrix which exists a circuit with complexity poly(n), how to find that circuit? (we also assume that the circuit is created only by four kinds of gates: hadamard,cnot,not,phase shift)
I am not seeking for an alorithm witch could definitly find it(if it exists, that's fine), or if there is any heuristic approach, that would be also good.
The reason for this question is that sometimes given me a unitary matrix (not too complicated), but I find I have no idea how to implement it with gates.
Even if sometimes I found a way to design a circuit for that unitary matrix, next time I meet another unitary matrix, I have to figure out another way to design it. is there any common methodology for design circuits with some basic gates given an arbitrary unitary matrix?
has this question been researched by someone or not?

The key words you are looking for are “logic synthesis”. The correspond (classical) logic synthesis techniques include the  Quine-McCluskey algorithm or Karnaugh mapping. I would search for “logic synthesis quantum” to see what techniques are useful.
